# Why is SP (apparently) stored on exception entry on Cortex-M3?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm

I am using a TI LM3S811 (a older Cortex-M3) with the SysTick interrupt to trigger at 10Hz. This is the body of the ISR:

```
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
    __asm__ volatile("sub r4, r4, #32\r\n");
}
```

This produces the following assembly with `-O0` and `-fomit-frame-pointer` with [gcc-4.9.3](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded). The `STKALIGN` bit is 0, so stacks are 4-byte aligned.

```
00000138 <SysTick_Handler>:
 138:   4668        mov r0, sp
 13a:   f020 0107   bic.w   r1, r0, #7
 13e:   468d        mov sp, r1
 140:   b401        push    {r0}
 142:   f1ad 0420   sub.w   r4, r4, #32
 146:   f85d 0b04   ldr.w   r0, [sp], #4
 14a:   4685        mov sp, r0
 14c:   4770        bx  lr
 14e:   bf00        nop
```

I don't understand what's going on with `r0` in the listing above. Specifically:

1) It seems like we're clearing the lower 3 bits of SP and storing it on the stack. Is that to maintain 8-byte alignment? Or is it something else?

2) Is the exception exit procedure is equally confusing. From my limited understanding of the ARM assembly, it does something like this:
    `SP = SP + 4;` `R0 = SP;`

Followed by storing it back to SP. Which seems to undo the manipulations until this stage.

3) Why is there a `nop` instruction after the unconditional branch (at `0x14E`)?

Comment: You should also tell gcc not to double-word-align the stack.

Comment: What is the gcc option to do that? I couldn't find one.

Comment: Good point. I thought the `interrupt` attribute could help, but that seems to do the opposite. Anyway, just try it. Either way, `STKALIGN` is not evaluated by the compiler, but by the CPU and means it shoall not align the stack on interrupt (otherwise it will push an extra word if the the stack is not aligned). This has nothing to do with the compiled code. The 8 byte-alignment is actually given by the ABI/(AA)PCS. Not sure if a different standard is suitable for CM3. Please post the full command line for gcc.

Comment: Stupid mistake! The `interrupt` attribute actually enables the doubleword stack alignment. Turns out the file I was modifying had the attribute declared on the function signature. Removing it does the trick!

Comment: I made that an answer. Fell free to ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ARM Procedure Calling Standard and C ABI expect an 8 byte (64 bit) alignment of the stack. As an interrupt might occur after pushing/poping a single word, it is not guaranteed the stack is correctly aligned on interrupt entry.

The `STKALIGN` bit, if set (the default) enforces the hardware to align the stack automatically by conditionally pushing an extra (dummy) word onto the stack.

The `interrupt` attribute on a function tells gcc, OTOH the stack might be missaligned, so it adds this pre-/postamble which enforces the alignment.

So, both actually do the same; one in hardware, one in software. If you can live with a word-aligned stack only, you should remove the `interrupt` attribute from the function declarations and clear the `STKALIGN` bit.

Make sure such a "missaligned" stack is no problem (I would not expect any, as this is a pure 32 bit CPU). OTOH, you should leave it as-is, unless you really need to safe that extra conditional(!) clock and word (very unlikely).

Warning: According to the ARM Architecture Reference Manual, setting STKALIGN == 0 is deprecated. Briefly: do not set this bit to `0`!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `-O0`, you should expect lots of redundant and useless code.  The general way in which a compiler works is to generate code with the full generality of everything that might be used anywhere in the program, and then rely on the optimizer to get rid of things that are unneeded.

1. Yes this is doing 8byte alignment.  Its also allocating a stack frame to hold local variables even though you have none.
2. The exit is the reverse, deallocating the stack frame.
3. The nop at the end is to maintain 4-byte alignment in the code, as you might want to link with non-thumb code at some point.

If you enable optimization, it will eliminate the stack frame (as its unneeded) and the code will become much simpler.

Comment: I compiled again with `-O2` and it generated identical code. Also, is 8-byte alignment necessary even on ISRs?

Comment: There is no stack frame generated, but the stack is 8 byte aligned as required by the AAPCS. This because the `interrupt` attribute tells gcc the stack may be not aligned properly, see my answer for details.

Comment: I still don't understand why we need to store the older stack pointer (stored into r0, in this case) on the stack.